# Regex with unicode in Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, ascii, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 and want to do a regex with some special characters. In my template Jinja, I call a filter that runs on Python, passing `text` like **unicode**.

```
def insert_link(text, link):

  artigo_pattern = r"art(\.|(igo))?\s?\d+\s?(o|º|\.)?"

  #Pattern with error
  paragrafo_pattern = r"(§\s?\d+\s?(o|º|\.)?)|(par(a|á|Á)grafo\s(u|ú|Ú)nico)"

  alinea_pattern = r"[a-z]\s?\)"

  finalPattern = ')|('.join([
    artigo_pattern , paragrafo_pattern, alinea_pattern
  ])
  finalPattern = ''.join([ "((", finalPattern, "))" ])

  mat = re.match(finalPattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

But it never recognizes the pattern "**§ 7o**" because § character.
When I replace r by u, does not recognize other patterns as "Parágrafo único".

So, how to do a general regex to all patterns above?

Comment: Are you sure this is the issue? `re.match(r'§', '§')` does return a match for me.

Comment: But it's not "§", it's u"§". With `re.match(ur'§', '§')` works, But it gives error in other patterns.

Comment: When I add ``return mat`` at the end of your function, both expressions are matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unicode literals and pass unicode strings to the `match` function:

```
>>> re.sub(ur"§|a|á|Á", u"_", u"Halo §Ásdf")
u'H_lo __sdf'
```